# 'Policy implementation' dummy as IV in panel data model: same across individuals?

Tags: panel-data, instrumental-variables

I am using a control function approach for panel data. I have an endogenous variable in the outcome equation. I take this endogeneity into account by adding the generalised residuals of a selection equation (with this endogenous variable as the dependent variable) to this outcome equation.

My dataset consists of approximately 80,000 observations, distributed across 13 years.

In the selection equation I need some instrumental variables, i.e. variables which influence the endogenous variable but not the outcome variable. I was thinking of using a dummy 'policy implementation', which is 0 for the first 7 years of the panel and 1 for the last 6 years of the panel. My reasoning is that this policy has a large impact on the endogenous variable, but absolutely no impact on the outcome variable. I received a comment from a reviewer: "This variable is the same across all units. How is it an IV then?"

Consequently, my question is: **can an IV be the same across individuals, but vary over time? Are there any papers which treat this topic?**

Note: 'policy implementation' is not the only IV, I have additional IV which does vary across individuals.

Comment: Don't Angrist and Krueger (1991) use an IV that only varies over time?

Comment: Is the endogenous regressor also only varying over time, but the same for each individual in a given time period?

Comment: @Durden: no, the endogenous regressor varies over time and varies over individuals.

Comment: @DmitriiPetrukhin, do you mean the paper on compulsary schooling? The authors use an individual-specific IV: the quarter of the year when the individual was born.

Comment: @Charlotte in that case your cross-sectionally invariant IV will remove all the variation in the endogenous regressor. It will work mathematically, but it changes the meaning of the coefficient.